# How can i creat a multiple rect by pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, draw, rect

i want to creat a game like Pong but just one player from downside, and multiple box from up side, when the ball hit the box, the box will disappear. I can't remember name of that game but i don't know hot to create multiple rectangles. I can draw it by easy way [image]

Comment: You can see this [post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-pygame/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) to draw a rectangle:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, width, height))
```

Use nested loops to draw create the locations of multiple rectangles

```py
rectwidth = 40
rectheight = 40
rectdist = 10

block_positions = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(2)
        x = 100 + i * (rectdist + rectwidth) 
        y = 100 + j * (rectdist + rectheight)
        block_positions.append((x, y))
```

Draw the rectangles in a loop:

```py
for x, y in block_positions:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, rectwidth, rectheight))
```